# Do I need to build my scripts every time I go back into Unity from my script editor?

Tags: unity, build-process

I saw a few Unity YouTubers who do not build their scripts when they are working.

But I always do it.

Do I have to?

Comment: What do you mean by "compiling your scripts" ? From your IDE ? Unity builds automatically the C# project when it detects any changes in the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you dont need to build your code from Visual Studio for example. Unity does that for you when it detects changes in relevant code.